# Deriving `ToHtml` for Newtype?

Tags: haskell, servant

Given:

```
λ: >import Servant.HTML.Lucid
```

I created a `newtype`:

```
λ: >newtype Foo = Foo String
```

However, it doesn't appear that there's an `ToHtml Foo` typeclass in scope:

```
λ: >instance ToHtml Foo

<interactive>:3:10: warning: [-Wmissing-methods]
    • No explicit implementation for
        ‘toHtml’ and ‘toHtmlRaw’
    • In the instance declaration for ‘ToHtml Foo’
```

Yet one exists for `String`:

```
λ: >:t toHtml
toHtml :: (Monad m, ToHtml a) => a -> HtmlT m ()
λ: >toHtml "foo"
foo
```

How can I get a `ToHtml Foo` without an explicit instance definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Foo` need to derive `ToHtml` class to be the instance of that class.
Since `Foo` is a `newtype` of `String` it can be done using:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
```

I guess, this code demonstrates, what you're looking for:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Lucid.Base

newtype Foo = Foo String deriving ToHtml

main = print $ toHtml (Foo "foo")
```